# Shortcut to switch off and on individual cellular network

Tags: iphone, ios, sim, cellular-carriers, shortcuts-app

iPhone iOS13 w/ dual SIMS: T-Mobile (EU) & AT&T (US). I need help shortcut script:

- IF I arrive home THEN

  - turn on airplane mode and WIFI
  - GO To Settings -- Cellular (Cellular Plans)
  - 1 Cellular plan (T-Mobile) Turn ON / 2 Cellular Plan (AT&T) Turn ON
- IF I leave home THEN

  - turn off airplane mode and
  - GO To Settings -- Cellular (Cellular Plans)and
  - 1 Cellular plan (T-Mobile) Turn ON / 2 Cellular Plan (AT&T) Turn OFF

This allows the user access to WIFI calling only while at home location and local cellular plan use while outside of home.

[Turning off Network completely: Not just 'data' but the complete network mobile line. Ex: T-Mobile is 'active' and AT&T turns off.]

Comment: Did anyone solve this? I have the same problem.

Comment: I can't believe such a simple operation as toggling a phone line on or off cannot be automated on iOS. What am I missing?

Answer (score 0):

With iOS - you can automate enabling airplane mode with Siri. Have you tested if you can say ‘Hey Siri - turn off AirPlane Mode”

Automation options in general are:

- Siri is the easiest if Apple has programmed that interface and operation
- Next easiest if third party / first party automation like [Shortcuts](https://apps.apple.com/us/app/shortcuts/id1462947752) and [Toolbox Pro](https://apps.apple.com/us/app/toolbox-pro-for-shortcuts/id1476205977) apps.
- Least easy is assistive touch and voice over. These have a learning curve and you may find it faster to perform a manual step - but they do automate powerfully by non-touch events or not traditional touch events.

As for the other part - how do you have Network Selection in your settings app and how do you accomplish the steps above manually? Putting down step by step might let someone who knows how to automate things help you without needing to see your phone or establish two service accounts.